# Setting color for bar chart in ng2-chart

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, ng2-charts

[image: I need like this]I am trying to set colors for bars in bar graph according to the range of values.

**TS**

```
  public barChartData: any[];
  public chartColors: any[];
    value = [] // This array have my values from DB like  [3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 6.5, 6, 1, 6.5, 3.5, 5.5]

    this.barChartData = [{
        data: this.value,
        label: 'Insulin'
    }]

    var l = this.value.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (this.value[i] <= 3) {
            this.chartColors = [{
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 9)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 9)'
            }]
        } else if (this.value[i] > 3 && this.value[i] <= 6) {


            this.chartColors = [{
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 62)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 62)'
            }];

        } else if (this.value[i] > 6) {

            this.chartColors = [{
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, -12)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, -12)'

            }];

        }

    }
```

This is not working out. Can any one tell me right way to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***The problem in your code :***

```
if (this.value <= 3) {
this.chartColors = [{
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 62)'
}]
}
```

When you are writing this if condition you are completely changing the 'this.chartColors' property. But your requirement is to change only the background color for those input which satisfy the mentioned condition. 
 The below example contains the right format for writing  chart colors.

```
public chartColors: Array<any> = [
{
  backgroundColor: ['rgba(63, 191, 127,  0.4)','rgba(191, 191, 63, 0.4)'],

   borderColor: ['rgba(63, 191, 127, 0.8)', 'rgba(63, 191, 191, 0.8)'],
  hoverBackgroundColor: ['rgba(63, 191, 127, 0.6)', 'rgba(63, 191, 191, 0.6)'],
  borderWidth: 2
}];
```

The backgroundColor or borderColor or hoverBackgroundColor contains array of colors. Each index value points to curesponding index value of the barChartData.data.

Here is the right format to write barChartData

```
 public barChartData: any[] = [{
  data: [],
  label: ''
}];
```

Your data will be placed in barChartData.data = [Here will be your required data]

***The conclusion is***:

**this.barchartData[0].data[index]** will have **this.chartColors[0].backgroundColor[index]** as bar color.

***Solution:***

So Finally Follow the below code you may solve you issue:

```
for (let index = 0; index < this.barChartData[0].data.length; index++) {
  if (this.barChartData[0].data[index] > 0 && this.barChartData[0].data[index] < 3 ) {
    console.log('>0' , this.barChartData[0].data[index]);
    this.chartColors[0].backgroundColor[index] = 'rgba(63, 191, 127,  0.4)';
  }
  if (this.barChartData[0].data[index] > 3 && this.barChartData[0].data[index] < 5) {
    console.log('>3' , this.barChartData[0].data[index]);
    this.chartColors[0].backgroundColor[index] = 'rgba(191, 63, 127, 0.4)';
  }
  if (this.barChartData[0].data[index] > 5 ) {
    console.log('>5' , this.barChartData[0].data[index]);
    this.chartColors[0].backgroundColor[index] = 'rgba(191, 127, 63,  0.4)';
  }
}
```

This one is a sample code.You give value according to your preference. If you find any difficulty in understanding my explanation feel free to ask.

**Replace the below with your code :**

```
public barChartData: any[] = [{
    data: this.value,
    label: 'Insulin'
}];
public chartColors: any[] = [{
   backgroundColor =[],
   borderColor = []
}];;
value = [] // This array have my values from DB like  [3.5, 2.5, 1.5, 
6.5, 6, 1, 6.5, 3.5, 5.5]

var l = this.value.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (this.barChartData[0].data[i] <= 3) {
     this.chartColors[0].backgroundColor[i] ='rgba(255, 205, 86,9)';
     this.chartColors[0].borderColor[i] = 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 9)';           

    } else if (this.barChartData[0].data[i] > 3 &&        
     this.barChartData[0].data[i] <= 6) {
     this.chartColors[0].backgroundColor[i] ='rgba(255, 99, 132, 62)';
     this.chartColors[0].borderColor[i] = 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 62)';

    } else if (this.barChartData[0].data[i] > 6) {
     this.chartColors[0].backgroundColor[i] ='rgba(54, 162, 235,-12)';
      this.chartColors[0].borderColor[i] = 'rgba(54, 162, 235, -12)';
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting barchartData from backend and storing it in array

Comment: yes. the barChartData[0].data = [store here]. 

 const dataBar = [];
 for (let index = 0; index < this.apiData.length; index++) {
          const elm = this.apiData[index];
          dataBar.push(elm.arrayData);  /*Write path of data as mentioned in your API */
        }        
        this.barChartData[0].data = dataBar;

Comment: i will edit my question now to show what exactly i done

Comment: Follow my suggestion and change the condition body, which i have explained in my answer. See the solution part in my answer. Compare the if condition in your code and mine. hope you ll get it now.

Comment: where data are plotting

Comment: The problem is created because you are changing the whole chartcolor like this  this.chartColors = [{
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 62)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 62)'
            }];

Actually you just need to change the color according to the data's index.
Now follow my solution part. I have changed the color for the data according to their indexing

Comment: should i remove my `   this.barChartData = [{
        data: this.value,
        label: 'Insulin'
    }]`

Comment: No , the problem is in the condition only. if condition. Please Follow my solution part.
The line           this.chartColors[0].backgroundColor[index] = 'rgba(63, 191, 127,  0.4)';
 is the ans. Yopu dont need to change the whole chartcolor . just change the background color according to the data

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'backgroundColor' of undefined I am getting this

Comment: I have directly written the replacement you need to do. Have a look to my answer. I have edited just now.

Comment: I have done some more editing. You may follow this. I have used this concept in my live project and it a success. If possible share your code in plunker. I ll edit there.

Comment: hi bro.. still core.js:12301 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: how to set three labels for this bro

Comment: I am glad my answer helped you finally. Ok now Do you want to set label like you have set label: 'Insulin'?

Comment: Yeah i want to set labels like 0-3 with yellow color, 3-6 with pink and above 6 with blue. I tried to set, but i can set only one

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html . In this link in the Dataset Properties
Its written that label can only take string values not arrays. SO not possible to change label. You can play with ticks.